# PHP Decode JSON variables

Tags: php, json, response

I have the following json file below that outputs the following information:

```
stdClass Object
(
[status] => OK
[droplet] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 567894
        [name] => Luna
        [created_at] => 2013-10-10T18:13:08Z

    )

)
```

I'm trying to get the [name] and save it to a variable called $serverName.
I've tried using the code below but have no luck :/

```
<?php
    $request = 'Link to JSON FILE';
    $response  = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonobj  = json_decode($response);

    $serverName = $jsonobj->name;
```

I've tried looking online but I'm having troubles getting this to work :/

Thanks a ton <3

Comment: Have you tried $jsonobj->droplet->name; ?

Comment: fail.. I've been trying this for the past hour, but I've been spelling it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. Just need to do;

```
$jsonobj->droplet->name;
```